# Publishing the project to Plesk Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, plesk, publishing

I have four projects in one solution

1. RapporAMS.Data (Contains the connection string and database access queries and entity framework installed, it also have connection string in app.config file same that of web.config in forth project)
2. RapporAMS.Service (Act as an interface between RapporAMS.Data and RapporAMS.MVC )
3. RapporAMS.Entities (Contains all the Entities and view models used in the solutions i.e business objects)
4. RapporAMS.MVC (MVC project front end of the application also have connection string in web.config and entity framework installed)

I have created the database in Plesk named "esssospa_AmsDB" with username and password. Then I used "import dump" to import  .bak file. Now, it is showing file size and the total number of tables in the database.

I am not sure about database has been attached to esssospa_AmsDB or not
After that. I winziped only RapporAMS.MVC project and uploaded it to the httpdocs directory on the server.

Then I changed the connection string in web.config **don't know how to change the connection string in app.config of RapporAMS.Data**. This may be the issue of the error.

- Problem 1: Database esssospa_AmsDB is not showing up in my SQL EXPRESS 2014 when I logged in using the credentials.
- Problem 2: Having 500-Internal Error when I access the website, further screenshot is attached. click @ [Database on Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Dax.png)

Comment: Questions about how to host software are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Dear i have hosted but i am having problem mentioned in the answer please reply and solve my issue thanks